# How do I create CSS after building a website?

Tags: css

Can anyone help with CSS files, I have created a website www.onlinesolutionsforcoaches.com and now realize I need to "clean" it up and have to add a css file. But How? Where do I start?

Comment: I would start over.

Comment: Just convert it to flash

Comment: How did you make that website if you don't know how to add a CSS file?

Comment: @Keltex convert it to flash? I hope that's a joke :p

Comment: You start by RTFM. http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/

Comment: @xil3: of course it's a joke. clearly he meant Silverlight.

Comment: I'm assuming you used a WYSIWYG editor to design the page. The problem is, it has placed most of its styling logic in outdated `<font>` tags or inline `style` attributes, and layout is done via tables. There is no point in attempting to move your styling data to an external style sheet as it's coupled too tightly with the markup. It really will be much easier to start over and do it right from the outset, as the entire page structure will likely change dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

Probably should start with a basic CSS primer.  This is a decent start point but really, google CSS Primer or Tutorial to get started.

http://wendypeck.com/css101.html

Answer (score 0):

Just read some book about CSS. I recommend you ["CSS: The missing manual"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526873).